# stylus: set font to percentage of width

Tags: stylus

A design for our page calls for the font size to be set to 4.5% of the current viewport width, and to max out at 43px.

Not sure how to accomplish this in Stylus -- `font-size: min(4.5vw, 43px)` is what I would assume that I would use, but it's giving me the `vw` calculation at all widths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stylus (and any preprocessor in general) cannot do that, because 4.5vw is calculating in a browser runtime, at compile time Stylus doesn't know the browser width.